# Recursive script in bash to convert photos to videos

Tags: bash, image, shell, video, ffmpeg

I am not a shell expert and I would like to know how to write a small algorithm (I think it is possible) to solve my problem.

I have an `output` directory which itself contains several folders for example `data_1` , `data_2`, etc. These folders also contain different versions, for example `version_1`, `version_2`. And finally these versions all contain an image folder `photos` which contains several thousand images in the form `000001.jpg`, `000002.jpg`, ...
I'm looking to convert all these `photos` folders into a video that takes the photos frame by frame. For example for the 2nd version of the dataset `data_1` I will do the following commands:

```sh
ffmpeg -i data_1/version_1/photos/%6d.jpg data_1/version_1/data_1_ version_1.mov

rm -r data_1/version_1/photos
```

But this implies that I have to rewrite by hand the command once the program is finished for a folder by changing the folder names and also the .mov file which must imperatively be of the form data_version.mov and saved at data/version/data_version.mov.

I would like a script that automates this procedure by going through all the `data` folders to create the videos BUT also by checking that if the video exists the script is not run on the current `version`.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: So `data_1/version_1/photos/` should be rename to `data_1/version_1/data_1_`? and all the photos files ending in `.jpg` should be named `version_1.mov` In your example?

Comment: @Marcel : Wouldn't the `find` command do what you want to achieve?

Comment: If `photos` is removed when `ffmpeg` succeeds, there shouldn't be a need to check for for an existing video - there will be no corresponding photos directory. Or do you mean only one video per list of versions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory name `photos` is *fixed*, would you please try:

```
while IFS= read -r dir; do                              # assign "dir" to the path to "photos"
    dir2=${dir%/photos}                                 # remove trailing "photos" dirname
    name=${dir2#*/}                                     # remove leading slash
    name=${name//\//_}                                  # convert slashes to underscores
    echo ffmpeg -i "$dir/%6d.jpg" "$dir2/${name}.mov"   # execute ffmpeg
    echo rm -rf -- "$dir"                               # rm "photos" directories
done < <(find . -type d -name "photos")                 # find dir named "photos" recursively
```

If the output looks good, drop `echo` and execute.